# Why ObjectMapper writeValueAsString return empty string?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I need to serialize Java `Object` to `JSON`.

But when I use `writeValueAsString` method this method returns me empty JSON Object.

Here is my `@RestController`:

```
public String getReportsFromReporter(
            @PathVariable(name = "from") String from, 
            @PathVariable(name = "to") String to) throws IOException {
    String url = "example.com";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectForRequestToReporter objectForRequestToReporter =
                               new ObjectForRequestToReporter();
    objectForRequestToReporter.setToken(somedata);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setEmployee(somedata);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setFrom(from);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setTo(to);
    String jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapper);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject, httpHeaders);
    String ans = restTemplate.postForObject(url , entity, String.class);
    String test = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                              .writeValueAsString(objectMapper);
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    return ans;
}
```

`System.out.println` shows this:

```
 { }
 {}
```

Gradle depedencies:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2")
```

Object class for serialize:

```
@Data
public class ObjectForRequestToReporter {
    private String token;
    private String employee;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private final int work_after = 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: You are really trying to do everythig yourself whic is already provided by the §restTemplate. Also you are writing the `objectMapper` as a string and not the object you want. But instead of using the objectmapper, ditch it and just put the `ObjectForRequestToReporter` in the `HttpEntity`. The `RestTemplate` will take care of the json conversion.

Comment: You are serializing the `objectMapper`, not your `objectForRequestToReporter`. `objectMapper` does not have any properties to serialize (it is not a data class). -> caused by a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in this line:

```
String jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapper);
```

Maybe it should be:

```
String jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectForRequestToReporter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapper);
```

You are trying to convert the `ObjectMapper` to json.

What you want:

```java
String jsonObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectForRequestToReporter);
```

However your code is doing basically what the `RestTemplate` already does, and thus can be greatly simplified by removing the `ObjectMapper` as you don't need it.

```java
public String getReportsFromReporter(@PathVariable(name = "from")String from, 
  @PathVariable(name = "to")String to) throws IOException {
    String url = "example.com";
    
    ObjectForRequestToReporter objectForRequestToReporter =
            new ObjectForRequestToReporter();
    objectForRequestToReporter.setToken(somedata);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setEmployee(somedata);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setFrom(from);
    objectForRequestToReporter.setTo(to);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(objectForRequestToReporter, httpHeaders);
    return restTemplate.postForObject(url , entity, String.class);
}
```